# Finishing android app on HOME button click

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

How to finish the application on `HOME` button click?

Answer (score 5):

You don't - just let Android suspend your app and tidy it up when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should only be finishing the Activity by detecting the click and calling finish() on the activity.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned before you really should consider NOT using this approach to finish your application.

Anywho: Here is some code you can use to detect Home-Button pushes and call appropriate functions.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This also detects the software home button afaik

Answer (score 2):

You can set the intent you used to start acitvity with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, and according to the doc:

> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
>
> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as
>   the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may
>   also be set with the noHistory attribute. Constant Value: 1073741824
>   (0x40000000)

This might fit the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Android did't gave permission to programmers to handle home button for user convenience. when user wants sudden exit from the application he will press the home button.